# Split on special non-space whitespace character

Tags: java, scala

I'm working with log files that look like this:

```
98.87.115.89 - - [12/Nov/2014:05:21:26 -0500] "GET /no_cache/bi_page?Log=1&pg_inst=600474500174606089&pg=mdot_fyc_pnt&platform=mdot&ver=10.c110&pid=157876860906745096&rid=157876731027276387&srch_id=-2&row=7&seq=1&tot=1&tsp=1&test_name=m_control&logDomain=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xyz.com&ref_url=http%3A%2F%2Fm.xyz.com%2F&z=44134 HTTP/1.1" 200 43 "http://m.xyz.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; SPH-L720 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/537.16" "98.87.115.89.1415786359690989" web79011
```

The data looks like it is SPACE separated but it's actually more complicated than that because there is whitespace after the GET and in the final line, for example between Mobile and Safari even though both words are part of the same element.

When I paste that into Excel and run a TextToColumns on space (and I'm not sure if my browser converts this special character to a plain space so you'll have to trust me on this), I get the following perfect split:

```
98.87.115.89|-|-|[12/Nov/2014:05:21:26 -0500]|"GET /no_cache/bi_page?Log=1&pg_inst=600474500174606089&pg=mdot_fyc_pnt&platform=mdot&ver=10.c110&pid=157876860906745096&rid=157876731027276387&srch_id=-2&row=7&seq=1&tot=1&tsp=1&test_name=m_control&logDomain=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xyz.com&ref_url=http%3A%2F%2Fm.xyz.com%2F&z=44134 HTTP/1.1"|200|43|"http://m.xyz.com/"|"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; SPH-L720 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/537.16" "98.87.115.89.1415786359690989"|web79011
```

Notice the whitespace characters after GET and after Mobile are NOT picked up as delimiters.  So that means some other whitespace character is being used.

But when I paste the text into Scala (a Java answer here would work too) and run .split(" "), using a regular space, it views all the whitespace as a space, which causes a lot of problems.

How can I figure out what special character is being used, and how do I split on just the spaces and not the special characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best choice is to use regular expressions to do this.
here is a reference link I found useful: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_regular_expressions.htm

Based on your sample string, this could be a pattern to try

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

 [...]
val str = [... your string to be matched ...]
val pattern1 = "(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})(?:.*)(\\[.*\])(?:.*?)(\".+?\")(?:.*?)(\\d+)(?:\\s)(\\d+)(?:\\s)(\".+?\")(?:.*?)(\".+?\")(?:.*?)(\".+?\")(.*)".r
```

in particular:

```
(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})  -> matches the IP address
(\\[.*\])                                    -> matches the date and time
(?:.*?)                                      -> matches the bare minimum number of
                                                characters between surrounding patterns
                                                groups
(\".+?\")                                    -> matches the parts between quotes
```

Of course the above pattern has pretty naive structure, you could improve it by using repetition marks and choosing more carefully some groups, but it should do the job for the sample you gave.

having the pattern in place, you can ..

```
val newstring = (pattern findAllIn str).mkString("|")
```

Please, notice that I wrote the above by heart, because I have no chance at the moment to check the code in scala, but I hope it can hint you towards a fully working solution.

Edit:

It come to me that probably your last need is not to get the string separated by "|" but rather to access all the matches as variables. In scala you can match against a pattern and achieve this easily:

```
val pattern(ip, date, getString, p1, p2, q1, q2, q3) = str
```

will store in `ip` the match of the first group, in `date` the second group and so on. All the arguments inside the parentheses are variables you can use to access the content of the group matching. Beware those will be string, so you may need to cast the correct types for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Excel's data import parser is smart enough to skip spaces that are in between quotes.

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to express a whitespace, since Unicode brings in some new ones.

I'd suggest using

```
\s+ //(normal whitespcaes, pre unicode)
```

or

```
\p{Z}+ //\p{Separator} which would match all Separator, even the ones introduced by unicode)
```

with a regular expression.

You could go the other way round and think what you need and split at the negation of that i.e. every non-whitspace character which could be expressed in a regular expression as

```
[^\w] or [\W]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more involved than String.split unfortunately, because you want to skip over spaces that are inside double quotes. 
There is a number of standard parsers, you may want to use, such as apache's [CSVParser](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html) for example. Or, if you don't care about corner cases like escaped double quotes inside a double-quoted field etc, something like this might work (I could not think of a way to write this in idiomatic scala ... would be interested to see if someone comes up with one):

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(inputString, " \"", true);
List<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>(tokens.length);
boolean inquotes = false;
while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String tok = tokens.nextToken();   
    if(tok == "\"") {
        inquotes = !inquotes;
        continue;
    }
    if(tok == " " && !inquotes) continue;
    fields.add(tok)
}
String result[] = fields.toArray(new String[fields.size()]);
```